# On PhpUnit how generate a list of failing/errorous/skipped tests

Tags: php, phpunit

On a phpunit because of a major refactor (generating a database for test purpoces) on our project I need to generate the report of all the failing tests in order to report it into my boss.

The current project executed the tests on the very same database that the app was being developed hence resulting poor quality tests. So I am replicating the database into a seperate one.

For that I need to compare which tests actually fail because of the testing database and which ones actually fail because on code bug. So in order to do that I need to record the Failing tests into a a file in order to compare the results between theese 2 executions:

1. Running them on the development database.
2. Running upon the testing database.

So How I can make phpunit to generate a list with the tests that:
 3. Are being Skipped
 4. Fail
 5. Stop due to a syntax error on the code

In order to compare them?

Comment: If I get your question right, this *should* be covered by [10. Logging](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.4/logging.html). Please take a look which log suits you well. Normally for me it's easy to process the XML logs as they are already machine readable. But it normally starts with finding a suitable log, e.g. for a visual representation others may already suit you well, don't forget to peek into the [Phpunit XML configuration section about logging](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.4/configuration.html#the-logging-element) as well.